# Cannot send Post Request Again after status 400 error even after correcting the request

Tags: java, angular, typescript, httprequest, spring-rest

I have an Edit Product page. I am editing and product. If I Edit the product name with an already existing product of that name and submit a post request to Java Spring REST API using JWT. I have validation and it returns status 400 which is right.
But the ***problem is*** that without reloading the page when I correct the name field and resend it, Status 400 is shown again with the same error message.
***This is my Submit funtion:***

```js
 onSubmit() {
    this.productSubmit = true;
    if (
      this.productFormGroup.valid &&
      !this.isTableEmpty &&
      this.isFormValid &&
      !this.isCustomTableEmpty
    ) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.product.name = this.f.name.value;
      this.product.productCategory = this.f.category.value;
      this.product.model = this.f.model.value;
      this.product.barcode = this.f.barcode.value;
      this.product.unit = this.f.unit.value;
      this.product.manufacturer = this.f.manufacturer.value;
      this.product.cost = this.f.cost.value;
      this.product.minimumStockLevel = this.f.minStock.value;
      this.product.description = this.f.description.value;
      this.product.length=this.f.length.value;
      this.product.width=this.f.width.value;
      this.product.height=this.f.height.value;
      this.product.weight=this.f.weight.value;
       if (this.f.brand.value) {
        this.product.brand = this.f.brand.value;
      } else {
        this.product.brand = null;
      }
      if (this.f.foreignName.value) {
        this.product.foreign_name=this.f.foreignName.value;
      } else {
        let foreignName=this.f.name.value;
        this.product.foreign_name=foreignName;
      }
      if (this.f.foreignSKU.value) {
        this.product.foreign_sku=this.f.foreignSKU.value;
      } else {
        let foreignSKU=this.f.model.value;
        this.product.foreign_sku=foreignSKU;
      }
      if (this.f.preferred_supplier.value) {
        this.product.preferred_supplier=this.f.preferred_supplier.value;
      } else {
        this.product.preferred_supplier=null;
      }
      this.product.prices = this.myPriceLists;
      let id = null;
      if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"]) {
        id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(["/loggedIn", "product", "list"]);
      }
      this.product.productCategory = this.selectedCategory;

      this.formData.append(
        "product",
        new Blob(
          [JSON.stringify(this.product, this.appService.jsonStringifier)],
          { type: "application/json" }
        )
      );

      this.images = this.images.concat(this.product.productImages);
      for (let image of this.images) {
        this.formData.append("images", image);
      }
      this.productService.updateProduct(this.formData, id).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.productService.resetProducts();
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: "info",
            summary: "Success",
            detail: "Product Successfully Edited"
          });
          this.router.navigate(["/loggedIn", "product", "list"]);
        },
        (errorResponse : HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.productErrors = this.appService.errorObjToMap(
            errorResponse.error.errors
          );
          this.productSuccess = errorResponse.error.success;
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: "error",
            summary: "Failure",
            detail: "Product not edited."
          });
         console.log(errorResponse.error.errors[0].message);

        },
        () => {
          this.successAlert = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

*** This is what my REST Controller looks like for this request***

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "save/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity addProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @Valid @RequestPart Product product, @RequestPart MultipartFile[] images, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        return saveProduct(id, product, images, bindingResult, request);
    }
```

Everything works fine except this.
I hope you can understand the problem. If you have any question ask me or anything that I might have missed to give.

Answer (score 0):

You should try re-setting the `messageService` object after the

```
console.log(errorResponse.error.errors[0].message);
```

I am not familiar with Angular, but React and hence suggested an answer from that perspective.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I tried to clear the message service after a delay but it still did not work.